# how to count values in a row that default instance have NONE?

Tags: mysql

Explain :

I have a table for Users and there is a column `android_token`, that can be null, but DEFAULT has NONE, means by default it doesn't sent null value for each row.

Now..

When I want to select all users that have their android_token not null, I can't get the result..

for example

```
SELECT * from tbl_users where android_token IS NOT NULL;
```

it gives me no sorting result, because rows that have it's android_token value are ok, but other users that have their android_token empty don't have even NULL value on it, in the structure of the table  android_token  DEFAULT IS NONE.

Can someone explain me, how can I update the table and send NULL value for each row that IS EMPTY only , or how can I sort users that have android_token with current configuration?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "DEFAULT IS NONE"? The default values is the string literal `'NONE'`? Or an empty string `''`? Please edit your question and add the table definition as `CREATE TABLE` statement, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result as tabular text (**no** screenshots) for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation**

Implicit defaults are defined as follows:

- For numeric types, the default is 0, with the exception that for
  integer or floating-point types declared with the AUTO_INCREMENT
  attribute, the default is the next value in the sequence.
- For date and time types other than TIMESTAMP, the default is the
  appropriate “zero” value for the type. For the first TIMESTAMP column
  in a table, the default value is the current date and time. See
  Section 10.3, “Date and Time Types”.
- For string types other than ENUM, the default value is the empty
  string. For ENUM, the default is the first enumeration value.

**Code**

If android_token is a string:

```
UPDATE tbl_users SET android_token=NULL WHERE android_token='';
```

This will change all empty cells to NULL